# Hive - Query to get Saturday as week start date for a given date

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive

I have an requirement in hive to calculate Saturday as week start date for a given date in hive sql.

Eg)

```
Date                   week_start    
03-27-2021             03-27-2021    
03-28-2021             03-27-2021    
03-31-2021             03-27-2021    
04-07-2021             O4-03-2021    
04-09-2021.            04-03-2021
```

I tried using pmod and other date functions but not getting desired output. Any insight  is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hive offers `next_day()`, which can be adapted for this purpose.  I think the logic you want is:

```
select date_add(next_day(date, 'SAT'), -7)
```

This is a *little* arcane.  `next_day()` gets the next date *after* the argument date with a given day of the week.  So, go to the next Saturday and then subtract 7 days for the start of the week.